# Remove Highlighted white-spaces

Tags: vba, loops, replace, ms-word, selection

I am trying to remove highlighted white space characters from Word text via a macro, but it hangs/loops whenever it encounters some comments or URLs (not all). How is this possible? And what would be the solution?

```
Sub checkforHighlightsOrg()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = "^\s+$" ' highlighted text having multiple white-space/invisible chars only
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    End With
    
    Dim bReplaced As Boolean
    bReplaced = False
    
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
        If Selection.Find.Found Then
             If regex.Test(Selection.text) Then
                bReplaced = True
                Selection.text = regex.Replace(Selection.text, "")
             End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    If bReplaced Then MsgBox "Highlighted white-spaces have been removed."
    
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rngTemp.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Execute
    End With
    If rngTemp.Find.Found = True Then
        MsgBox ("There have been non-white-space highlights found.")
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Another version I tried is as follows:

```
Sub checkforHighlightsV2()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = "\s+" ' highlighted text having multiple white-space/invisible chars only
    ActiveDocument.Select
      
    
    Dim regex2 As Object, str As String
    Set regex2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
     
    With regex2
      .Pattern = "\s"
      .Global = True 'If False, would replace only first
    End With

    
    
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    With Selection.Find
        .text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    End With
    
    Dim bReplaced As Boolean
    bReplaced = False
    Dim a As Range

    
    
    
restart:
    
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
        If Selection.Find.Found Then
    'Selection.MoveEnd wdParagraph, 1
    
     
    Set a = Selection.Range.Duplicate
    'Debug.Print Asc(a.text)
    
    'a.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    
    Dim res As String
     
    If regex.Replace(Replace(a.text, Chr(160), ""), "") = "" Then
    Debug.Print "empty"
    Selection.Delete
    End If
     
'    If a.text = vbCr Or a.text = vbLf Or a.text = vbCrLf Or a.text = vbNewLine Or a.text = vbTab Then
'   ' Debug.Print "newline"
'       bReplaced = True
'                Selection.Delete
'                GoTo restart
'
'    End If
'    If a.text = " " Then Selection.Delete
'
''
''             If regex.Test(a.text) Then
''                bReplaced = True
''                'a.text = regex.Replace(a.text, "")
''                Selection.Delete
''
''             End If
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    If bReplaced Then MsgBox "Highlighted white-spaces have been removed."
    
    Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range

    With rngTemp.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Execute
    End With
    If rngTemp.Find.Found = True Then
        MsgBox ("There have been non-white-space highlights found, this usually means default text.")
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I initially thought that I should not replace text while having a search selection active, so I tried to fix it by creating version 2 and calling selection.delete but somehow it does not work either.

The normal search dialog does not never loops, but the white-space character is not allowed there.
Thank you for your help.

Edit: I also tried this one (removes highlight only; does not remove the white-spaces, also when there is a newline/new paragraph that is highlighted whenever I hit enter for inserting text - this suggests that the markup/highlight is active on the newline/paragraph char - I tried some variations like ^w^p but I cannot use it in combination with 'Use wildcards' option when I want to use an OR operator)

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = False
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^w"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchFuzzy = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Latest version:

```
Sub RemoveHighlightedWhiteSpace()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Highlight = True
      .Replacement.Highlight = False
      .text = "[ ,^9,^11,^12,^13," & Chr(160) & "," & Chr(164) & "]{2,}"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried doing an advanced find in Word using ^w as the find text?

Comment: Yes I tried, I edited the post with that result.

Comment: ^w will find tab, space, non-breaking space and 1/4 em space. Leaving replacement text blank will delete those characters, not just remove highlighting. Which characters, specifically, are you looking to replace?

Comment: It removes the highlight, but when I point the mouse/cursor in the middle of the page (at the left side it was previously yellow highlighted) horizontally it stays there blinking which suggests that the empty replacement does not take place?

Comment: Its working for me in O365. Which characters, specifically, are you looking to replace?

Comment: Hmm I got Office 2016; maybe that's the problem. Preferably SPACE, vbCr, vbLf,vbCrLf,vbNewLine,vbTab and NBSP (=char 160). Somehow when I run the replace macro using the last code part, it get cleared, but when I hit enter/return at the end of some line, then the characters I type are highlighted. This suggests that there are still some invisible markups.

Comment: For example, after running the macro, and I type after line with TAB, TAB+SPACE or EMPTYLINE (enter/paragraph only) or I hit enter after it, the next line starts highlighted when I type. These can be found when searching for 'Highlight' only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. The only character that I can't find a way of including is vbLf.

To remove highlighting you need to use `Format = True` but this will not remove the characters, so has to be run separately.

```
Sub DeleteHighlightedWhiteSpace()
   'finds at least any 2 of vbTab, vbVerticalTab, vbFormFeed, vbCr, non-breaking space
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Highlight = True
      .text = "[ ,^9,^11,^12,^13," & Chr(160) & "]{2,}"
      .Replacement.text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub RemoveHighlighting()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Highlight = True
      .Replacement.Highlight = False
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: What you are trying to achieve is still unclear. From your comments it seems as though you are trying to remove all highlighting from an entire document. If so then there is a simple way to do that:

```
Sub RemoveAllHighlighting()
   Dim story As Range
   For Each story In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
      story.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
   Next story
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I concluded that it is not very useful to delete those highlighted whitespace (did would mess up the layout). I changed your version a little (see main post). It still does not remove invisible highlight from table cells (I used ^7 and chr(164) as "end of cell" marker, the first is not allowed apparently). My purpose is to clear all highlights for whitespaces which works almost now, except for those in cells. After that I need to find non-white space highlights. but [!^w] does not work.

Comment: @Mat90 - it is still unclear what your exact goal is here. It would have been better if you had included in your question screenshots showing before/after.

Comment: @Mat90 - If all you want to do is clear all highlighting from the document then that is precisely what the RemoveHighlighting routine in my answer does.

Comment: Yes it works, after your replace sub, except for 'empty' cells (when I search for highlight it finds ones in cells)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The goal is to remove all highlights on invisible characters. So when hitting return I do not start with typing with highlight on. After that, I need to alert (messagebox) the reviewer that there are some texts that are highlighted (before that I should clear all false positive highlights, i.e. highlights that are invisible, so that only the valid that need attention remain). Initially, I thought I would perform some invisible character cleanup (that are highlighted), like double highlighted spaces but that is not my focus anymore since it may mess up the layout.

Comment: It still does not remove the highlights from empty table cells (highlight text within cell and press backspace until no text is left) after I run the macro. I tried several combinations of Chr(13)&Char(7), but does not work. When I start typing it somehow gets highlighted.